# Checking if PHP Variables are and aren't NULL

Tags: php

UPDATE:

The following code

```
function findNowPlayingCondition () {
if (isset($nowplayingname) && isset($nowplayingartist)) {$nowplayingcond = '1'; };
if (isset($nowplayingname) && !$nowplayingartist) {$nowplayingcond = '2'; };
if (!$nowplayingname && isset($nowplayingartist)) {$nowplayingcond = '3'; };
if (!$nowplayingname && !$nowplayingartist) {$nowplayingcond = '4'; };
echo "$nowplayingcond";
}
```

always comes back with '4', again, I am stumped.

====================

I am trying to create a PHP if/then statement that *if* $nowplayingname has a valid string in it, and $nowplayingartist *is not* set, is '', or is *NULL*, it will set $nowplayingcond as '2'.

`if (var_dump(isset($nowplayingname)) && !$nowplayingartist) {$nowplayingcond = '2'};`

I am getting a parse error when this executes, I suspect it has something to do with `var_dump(isset(`, but I am not certain.

Comment: Why are you using var_dump() here? Remove it and your error goes away.

Comment: More importantly, why are you using isset in a var dump? isset returns true or false and is designed for IF statements. put the vardump iside an ifstatement if you want to do that

Comment: @JohnConde Your comment is not quite true. The missing semicolon is the error cause.

Comment: Should I just be able to use `isset($nowplayingname)` and have it work as needed @NoLiver92

Answer (score 1):

This will do.

```
if(!empty($nowplayingname) && !isset($nowplayingartist))
{
$nowplayingcond = 2;
}
```

Comment: I have `if (!empty($nowplayingname) && !isset($nowplayingartist)) {$nowplayingcond = '2';}` and it's showing a parse error.. what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the syntax error:

```
if (var_dump(isset($nowplayingname)) && !$nowplayingartist) {$nowplayingcond = '2';};
                                                                            // ---^
```

Further suggestions:

- Indent your code properly and don't use one-liners that way:

  ```
  if (var_dump(isset($nowplayingname)) && !$nowplayingartist) {
    $nowplayingcond = '2';
  }
  ```
- Why do you use `var_dump()` in an IF statement? Apart from the fact that `var_dump()`'s return value will always evaluate to a falsy boolean, the line doesn't make sense (logic error).
- Use more readable variable names:

  ```
  $nowPlayingName
  $nowPlayingArtist
  ```

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down. It's obviously right. I mean, the code here won't work as you expect (`var_dump` will always return something `false`-y), but it's the reason for the error.

Answer (score -2):

You are right, var_dump should not be there. var_dump() is used for debugging.

Following code would be enough:

`if(isset($nowplayingname)) { ... }`